# Canada Visa Fee payment question

Tags: visas, canada, terminology

I want to visit my friend in Canada, so I think I need a tourist visa (she has already sent me an invitation). I visited VFS Global (a company that handles visa applications in Georgia) and they told me about the documents I need to gather and that I should make a payment [online](https://eservices.cic.gc.ca/epay/welcome.do?lang=en), print out the payment and give it to them with documents. I am submitting a paper application and not an online visa application.

The problem I encounter is that I can't find the tourist payment option [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B82Fa.png), the closest thing I found is in **immigration** is an option called 'Temporary Residence'. However here I still can't find anything close to tourist visa [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELZi0.png).

Am I doing something wrong or should I select something out of this?

Comment: [Temporary Resident Permit](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/inadmissibility/permits.asp) = tourist visa. But this depends on your citizenship so you might wanna check the link I gave.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply but i don't understand one thing why would they put temporary resident permit in immigration? i have no desire to immigrate i just want to see the country :) and I am from Georgia (live there as well)

Comment: If you are an American citizen you [do not need a visa or an eTA](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-result.asp?country=US&result=3&message=0&standard=3&q3=). You can find out more about document requirements on the link I gave.

Comment: Different Georgia :) Country Georgia, one question you linked Temporary resident permits page however when i look in immigration fees i can only see Temporary resident visa. are they both the same ? you can see what i am talking about in the screen shot.
http://i.imgur.com/1QnUzKP.png

Comment: permit and visa are not the same. Permit is a document allowing you to legally be in Canada. Visa is a stamp which will be in your passport allowing you to enter Canada.

Comment: Canada calls its tourist visa a "temporary resident visa". The same as business visas, transit visas, student visas...

Comment: If you are a citizen of Georgia and do not have a U.S. Green Card, you will likely need a Canadian visa to visit Canada. You can find information about the various Canadian visa fees on the Citizenship & Immigration Canada (CIC) website at: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/fees/fees.asp#visas_permits Simply scroll down to “Applications for Electronic Travel Authorizations, visas and permits” and you will see the Canadian visa fee information for Visitor Visas (also known as Temporary Resident Visas), including for single entry or multiple entry visas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the [screenshot you provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELZi0.png), you need to select "**Temporary Resident Visa - (single or multiple entry) - ...**" (costs $100). "Temporary Resident Visa" is basically the Canadian legal term for a tourist visa.

Do **not** select "Temporary Resident Permit" (for $200), this is for a completely different purpose (it's for people who are inadmissable but are asking for an exception).